# CLIPS - How to relate 2 different deftemplates types when creating a defrule

Tags: clips

I am using CLIPS 6.3 to develop a simple production management algorithm.
Currently I have a deftemplate for product orders and another one for product details.

```
(deftemplate orderSheets
  (slot orderID (type INTEGER))
  (slot orderDate (type INTEGER))
  (slot product (type STRING))
  (slot quantity (type INTEGER))
  (slot deliverDate (type INTEGER))
)

(deftemplate productInfoSheets
  (slot productID (type STRING))
  (slot productStock (type INTEGER))
  (slot prodTime (type INTEGER))
  (slot maximumProduction (type INTEGER))
)
```

My doubt is how can I create a rule that relates the product order quantity (available in orderSheets) vs the available stock (available in productInfoSheets.

Thank you for your support,
Joan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example rule comparing order quantity to available stock:

```
(defrule not-enough
   (orderSheets (quantity ?quantity))
   (productInfoSheets (productStock ?stock))
   (test (> ?quantity ?stock))
   =>)
```